# Enabling usage of feature with boolean variable and value

Tags: c++, oop, architecture

Sometimes in a class which implements sort of algorithm, I would like user to be able to enable or disable certain feature, let's say scaling of some input values. Sometimes I see following code for that (with bool/float values set in constructor):

```
class A
{
private:
  bool enableScaling;
  float scaleFactor;

public:
  float foo(float x) const {
    ...

    if(enableScaling) {
      x *= scaleFactor;
    }

    ...
  }
};
```

Two variables for this purpose is not clear for me and I'm looking for advices for such situations.

In case of scale, I can omit boolean variable at all and set default `scaleFactor = 1.0f` (neutral) and I guess it would be okay for me. Sometimes "feature parameter value" can only be positive, so I might set its default value to -1 to show that this one is disabled, but sometimes it is not the case as well (all values allowed).

What is your approach for such situations in general?

Comment: If you don't have the `enableScaling` variable, the multiplication must *always* be done. And even when `scaleFactor` is equal to `1.0` the compiler can't know it and therefore can't optimize it. Checking a boolean variable will almost always be more efficient than whatever operation you want to enable/disable. Not to mention that the optional processing won't always such a simple thing, so there might not be any possible default value that could be used.

Comment: Maybe more on-topic in [Software Engineer SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yea, @FranklinYu, wasn't sure though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collapse `enableScaling` and `scaleFactor` to `std::optional<scaleFactor>`.

This is the C++17 way.

Prior to that, `boost::optional` was a choice.

In your specific case, defaulting `scaleFactor` to `1.0f` is an option, since multiplying a `float` by `1.0f` must preserve the original `float` by the IEEE754 standard (assuming your platform conforms to that).

Answer (score 1):

> What is your approach for such situations in general?

That can't be answered once and for all, it depends on the circumstances, possible other options that enable changing the behavior of your class etc. (as you already said, an integral value `-1` might make sense to indicate a special case, if the valid range is positive or non-negative).

However, you describe a common scenario that can be handled in a uniform way, i.e., you have a certain value that *can* change the behavior of your class, but only if it's set/present. In this case, use a [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) (or, if you can't use C++17, [boost::optional](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)) data member storing the value in question (or not). It adds a null state to your data member, expressing exactly what you were trying to achieve: if the value is there, use it, otherwise, don't. This is more expressive, because it documents your intention instead of relying on a particular value.